# Is there a way to use a nonlinear stepsize in a vb.net loop?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to do the following c statement in vb.

```
for(int i = 2^20; i > 0; i/=2)
{
   printf("%d\n",i); 
}
```

In vb would look similar to:

```
For i As Integer = 2^32 to 0 Step /2
   Console.Out.Writeline("{0}", i)
Next
```

Specifically, the variable where i is divided by 2 each iteration is not 
legal vb.

Is there a way to write this using a For statement that is allowed?

Comment: Just a pointer: `^` in C and VB mean different things.

Comment: And another detail, you don't need the `Out` in `Console.Out.Writeline()`

Answer (score 4):

No, the FOR loop in VB is shorter but less flexible.

And the obvious work-around is of course a While loop.

```
' untested
Dim i As Integer = 2^30  ' 2^32 will overflow
While i >= 0
   Console.Writeline("{0}", i)
   i = i Div 2
End While
```

Comment: That loop's going to run for a while! ;)

Comment: On a more serious note, I think this is a good answer: since  a C/C++ for() loop can always be rewritten as a while() loop, it makes sense that a "non-standard" for() loop translates to a While rather than a For when you translate to VB.

Answer (score 1):

There are two typical approaches:

1. Derive a formula to convert a linear (preferably integer-value) index into whatever values are needed for the loop, and then employ such a formula.

   Use a method to generate one or more "IEnumerable"s to return the proper values in sequence and then replace the "For" with a "For Each"

The former approach is the one I usually use; I believe LINQ includes some methods to facilitate the latter approach (something like Enumerable.Range) but I don't know the details.